# jquery cookie for show hide script

Tags: jquery

I am currently working on a small interface for which I use a very very simple show and hide script.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#hide").click(function(){
        $(".advanced").hide();
        $(".basic").show();
      });
      $("#show").click(function(){
        $(".advanced").show();
        $(".basic").hide();
      });
    });
```

The purpose of it is to hide and show a certain element within the navigation (basic and advanced view so to speak). My question now is how can I combine this with a cookie plugin? I would like that the preference stays saved and not always jump back to the "basic" view if I change to a different page.

Thank you very much,
Daniel

Comment: should it be the same even if you close borwser and open it up again ?

Comment: Currently the page starts with the "basic view" - if I "switch" to the  "advanced view" the additional buttons will be revealed, however if I am to open up another page or reload the current one it jumps back to "basic".

Comment: Have you considered using local storage for this?  http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May you have a look at [LocalStorage](http://t3n.de/news/html5-local-storage-daten-offlinebetrieb-speichern-350314/) (in german, can't find some in english)

Here is some in english too [LocalStorage EN](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/04/how-to-use-local-storage-for-javascript/)

**(because not all people allow cockies)**

You can store data like

```
localStorage.setItem("key", "value");

localStorage.getItem("key");
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ockuue0g/) (a way how you could do it)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".advanced").css('display', localStorage.getItem('advanced'));
    $(".basic").css('display', localStorage.getItem('basic'));

    $("#hide").click(function () {
        $(".advanced").hide();
        $(".basic").show();
        localStorage.setItem('advanced', 'none');
        localStorage.setItem('basic', 'block');
    });

    $("#show").click(function () {
        $(".advanced").show();
        $(".basic").hide();
        localStorage.setItem('advanced', 'block');
        localStorage.setItem('basic', 'none');
    });
});
```

Comment: exactly what I wanted to write +1

Comment: Thank you very much, I will give this method a try !

Answer (score 0):

Using [JQuery's COOKIE plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($.cookie("state") == "hide") {
        $("#hide").click();
    } else {
        $("#show").click();
    }
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $.cookie("state", "hide");
        $(".advanced").hide();
        $(".basic").show();
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $.cookie("state", "show");
        $(".advanced").show();
        $(".basic").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello and thank you very much for your suggestion. I have tried this method, however it does not seem to work on my end

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($.cookie("show")==1){
    $(".advanced").show();
    $(".basic").hide();
  } else{
    $(".advanced").hide();
    $(".basic").show();
  }
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $(".advanced").hide();
    $(".basic").show();
    $.cookie("show", 0);
  });
  $("#show").click(function(){
    $(".advanced").show();
    $(".basic").hide();
    $.cookie("show", 1);
  });
});
```